# How to populate an embedded database (such as hsqldb) on creation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, integration-testing, hsqldb

My setup is hibernate / JPA using hsqldb for doing integration tests. I would like to be able to use a sql script to populate some test data into the database.

Essentially I'm looking for an equivalent of Spring's

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data-hsql.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Except for this project using Spring is not an option for me. I've read various hsql articles suggesting this is possible using file mode and pointing the path at the script but I haven't been able to get this working.

My **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="test-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:test-data-hsql"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

The **test-data-hsql.script** does get run but there is always an error.

If I include the DDL statements in the script to create I get

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid schema name: INFORMATION_SCHEMA
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getUserSchemaHsqlName(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
```

If I exclude the DDL statements (hoping I can rely on hbm2ddl.auto = create) then I get

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ONETESTUSER
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getUserTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.processStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readLoggedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone have an example with a working script file or a better way to do this? I'm not necessarily tied to hsqldb if there is an alternative that can support this feature.

**Update**
The Minimal Script I am using to produce the error has no reference to INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
drop table AccessToken if exists
create table AccessToken (id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), createdAt    timestamp not null, lastAccessedAt timestamp, token varchar(255) not null, expirationPolicyId varchar(255) not null, userId varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
insert into ACCESSTOKEN (id, createdAt, lastAccessedAt, token, expirationPolicyId, userId) values (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'welcome1', 'oneDayPolicy', 'jtrotter');
```

Comment: What are the results of executing the script via plain vanilla JDBC call ?

Comment: can you post the SQL, namely the part with INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: Posted the SQL, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need the DDL statements in the script, otherwise the database is empty and you get the second error.

The problem is in the script, is has reference for mySQL specific meta data schema INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Remove reference to objects in that schema so that the create tables can complete.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated the post with the sql script being used - there is no explicit reference to INFORMATION_SCHEMA, is this some kind of default being used by hsqldb?